# Start watching a Provider when a button Is Pressed - Riverpod Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

In my application I want to start watching a provider after a button is pressed,
by default the provider will be called from the first build.

here is the code:

```
final userNameProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 'text');

class Example extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    //this is the provider
    ref.watch(userNameProvider);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          "some text",
        ),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text(''))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The provider should be called for the first time when the button is pressed(not when the widget builds) and after that it should be watched every times it's value(state) changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch providers conditionally. with additional provider: isWatch, conditionalProvider.

in console, `build` prints at the first time, and every time press change name only after pressed start watch

sample code

```
final isWatch = StateProvider((ref) => false);
final userNameProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 'text');
final conditionalProvider = Provider.autoDispose((ref) {
  final watch = ref.watch(isWatch);
  if (watch) {
    return ref.watch(userNameProvider);
  }
  return ref.read(userNameProvider);
});

class TestWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TestWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    print('build');
    final userName = ref.watch(conditionalProvider);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(userName),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            ref.read(isWatch.notifier).state = true;
          },
          child: const Text('start watch'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            ref.read(userNameProvider.notifier).state =
                'change name ${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}';
          },
          child: const Text('change name'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not be using StateNotifier (or ChangeNotifier or StateProvider) any more.  Your code is great... just change that StateNotifier into a straight Notifier, and life is good.

Comment: oh,, i don't use riverpod, so i didn't know that. thanks for information :)